# Firestore snapshot listener: 'null is not an object' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Here is what I am trying to do with my React Native app using Firestore:

1. If the user is signed in, activate snapshot listener and save the value as a state.
2. If the user is signed out, set the state as null.

When the user is signed in, the code works just fine. However, when the user signs out, the error prompt 'null is not an object (evaluating doc.exists)' shows up.

What might be wrong with the below code? Any advice? Thanks!

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if (user) {
    firestore().collection('points').doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(
      (doc)=>{
        if (doc.exists){
            setPoints(doc.data());
        }
        else {
            setPoints(null);
        }
      }
    )
  }
  else {
    setPoints(null);
  }
},[user]);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail which line of code generates the error.  Also, you should add code to check the query for errors.  If you have security rules that require a user to be signed in, the query will fail, and you'll never know that happened.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems here.

1. `if (user) {}` is obviously evaluating to `true`. I'd clarify by changing it to `if (user !== null` (or `undefined` or whatever it is when a user signs out).
2. Your snapshot is probably still listening and throwing said error because you haven't unsubscribed from it. The React documentation has a good section on [`cleanup` from subscribe functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1).

Basically you need to wrap your `onSnapshot()` inside a named function, then return that function from the `useEffect()`.